# Grocery CRUD: How to debug Add / Edit errors

Tags: sql, debugging, addition, edit, grocery-crud

I have a N:M relation beetween 'Museum' and 'Category'. Three tables:

**Museum**: id, name, ...

**Category**: id, name, ...

**Museum_x_Category**: museum_id, category_id

And have set a N:M relation with a sentence like:

```
 $crud->set_relation_n_n('Museum Categories', 'Museum_x_Category', 'Category', 'museum_id', 'category_id', 'name', 'category_id' );
```

I'm getting "An error ocurred on insert" errors when adding, and "An error has occurred on saving." when editing/uploading.

I guess it is due to an **SQL error**, and i'd like to see the SQL sentences running behind.

Does anyone know how to see it?

PHP: 5.3.5

MySQL: 5.1.14

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. There were two problems:

1.- there was a non-utf8 character in the relation name:

```
$crud->set_relation_n_n('Categorías', 'Museum_x_Category', 'Category', 'museum_id', 'category_id', 'name', 'category_id' );
```

now replaced by:

```
$crud->set_relation_n_n('Categorias', 'Museum_x_Category', 'Category', 'museum_id', 'category_id', 'name' );
```

(note the í in Categorías, which means Categories in Spanish).

2.- there was a problem with the last parameter ('category_id'). Note that i've removed it. With the parameter included, it was assigning all the museums to the first category, always, whatever category i select.

It works as desired now :)